# Data-Icon Image

Tags: jquery, html

Good afternoon, within the tag data-icon i need to add the Facebook img and the link img.
I downloaded a JQuery mobile pack, but how would I add the images with the HTML code.
Kind regards

```html
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/SOULTRAINRADIOBRISTOL/" style="font-family:open-sans; font-size:16px; font-weight:100; border:none; text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; text-align:left;" class="ui-btn ui-icon-facebook ui-btn-icon-left">Facebook</a>
```

Comment: I don't think jQuery mobile includes a FB icon by default. Do you mean you downloaded an additional set of icons and are trying to use those?

Comment: Yeah, I downloaded a JQuery packk with all the icons and data-icon etc...

Answer (score 0):

Create a hyperlink with an image in it,

```html
<a target="_blank" title="find us on Facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/PLACEHOLDER"><img alt="follow me on facebook" src="//login.create.net/images/icons/user/facebook_30x30.png" border=0></a>
```

You may replace the `PLACEHOLDER` with `groups/SOULTRAINRADIOBRISTOL/`

You don't need jQuery for this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.
Would the line read.

```html
   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/SOULTRAINRADIOBRISTOL/" style="font-family:open-sans; font-size:16px; font-weight:100; border:none; text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; text-align:left;" target="_blank"><img alt="follow me on facebook" src="//login.create.net/images/icons/user/facebook_30x30.png" border=0></a>
```